# Using a processor without to endpoint

Tags: java, apache-camel

Pretty new to Camel. I need to wiretap a processing pipeline, and
inspect the events flowing inside, and sending statsd metrics. The code
would look like something like this:

```java
Processor statsdProcessor = new StatsDProcessor(); 
...
from("disruptor:wiretap").process(statsdProcessor);
```

The `disruptor:wiretap` is already wired to the main pipeline.

I am wondering what is the implication of using prossor without
`to()` endpoint? Will the `exchanges` sit in the memory because
no where to go until timeout, or overwritten because buffer is full?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frankly at the lowest level, then inside Apache Camel, its all just `processor`, eg a `to` is a specialzed `processor` etc.

So when a message is routed by Camel, its basically just

```
from X
  process
  process
  process
  ...
```

So there is no implication to define a route in Camel without any `to`. As it all is just from -> process -> process etc.

Answer (score 1):

That's a "sink" - it only has an input and no output (or at least no output which goes again into the pipeline). Other examples are file sinks (writes data to a file), database sinks, etc.

The opposite is a "source" - something which has no `from()` and only a `to()`. These are triggered by external signals (i.e. not by the Camel framework) and they pump data into the pipeline (where Camel takes over). Common examples are cron jobs (time based trigger), REST services, services which are connected to a queue system like [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) or [MQSeries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_WebSphere_MQ).